# Why was my tag-wiki excerpt edit rejected, even though it makes the description more accurate?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I've personally weeded out at least ten mistagged posts, that confused Clipper the ***programming language*** with Clipper-lib the ***polygon clipping library***:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666756
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666684
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666681
4. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666567
5. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710273
6. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710266
7. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710263
8. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710261
9. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710217
10. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710290

I've decided to add a disambiguation note to one of the tags wiki, because people are obviously misled by the description as shown by my list of suggested (and approved) edits.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10710258

It's been **approved** by **one** person, and **rejected** by **three** people, with the reason of:

> This edit **does not make the post** even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, **more accurate** or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

---

I've read about [writing great tag wikis](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and I think I've provided ***basic guidance on when to use the tag***. But because it was rejected by 3 high-reputation users, now I'm wondering:

**How should a good tag-wiki excerpt edit look like, in order to be approved?**

Comment: Tag wiki editing is very hit-or-miss, far more so than pretty much any other reviewed action on the site.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is somewhat unfortunate that your wiki excerpt didn't get approved. I can only guess why the reviewers did so, but I assume they considered it to be not clear enough what your intention was.

I went ahead and edited that excerpt in your spirit:

> Member of the xBase family of languages. Use this tag for questions about coding in that language. For questions about the line and polygon clipping library use the tag clipperlib instead.

I added a wiki as well, again explaining there as well to not use the tag for questions about the clipper library.

Don't be too disappointed if now and then a suggested edit doesn't get approved. If you keep an eye on them, as you seem to do, you'll do fine.

Answer (score 12):

Your suggested edit was:

> Member of the xBase family of languages **(not to be confused with
>   "clipperlib", the line and polygon clipping library)**. Use this tag for
>   questions about coding in that language.

My reasoning for rejecting your edit was that this doesn't make it easier to read. It's the first line of a tag wiki that should succinctly describe what the tag is about. Adding something between parentheses in the first line that is actively *not* what the tag is about makes it harder to read in my opinion.

Had I known what effort you put into this, I would have looked at it more sympathetically certainly, and I think the way that @rene resolved it is surely nicer because it puts your remark at the end of the tag wiki.

But honestly, the problem with mistagging is not - as far as I see it - that the poster read the tag wiki and didn't understand it (because reading the tag wiki should already make clear to any clipperlib user that the [clipper] tag wasn't about it). The problem is that these people added the tag *without looking* at the tag wiki.

So no matter how much more you add to a tag wiki to direct users to the right tag, it is not going to have a lot of effect on mistagging.

Comment: This makes it sound like it may be worthwhile to replace the "clipper" tag with a less ambiguous "clipper-language" tag.